# Let $A,B⊂R^n$, if $ A $ is measurable and $m∗(A△B)=0$ show $B $is measurable and $m(B)=m(A)$ where $ m∗ $ denotes as outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

It seems very trivial, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: If I tell you that $(A\cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = A \triangle B$, i.e. the symmetric difference, does that help you?

Comment: Try using the completeness of the measure and prove that A ∩ B is measurable.

Comment: What is $A\cap B?

Comment: @ErikJoensson Actually, the original problem is m*(A△B), I just don't know how to print triangle notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the universe we are working in.

Observe that $R\cap B\subseteq\left(R\cap A\right)\cup\left(A\bigtriangleup B\right)$
and $R\cap A\subseteq\left(R\cap B\right)\cup\left(A\bigtriangleup B\right)$
for any $R\subseteq X$.

An outer measure is subadditive and monotone, so:

$m^{*}\left(R\cap B\right)\leq m^{*}\left(R\cap A\right)+m^{*}\left(A\bigtriangleup B\right)=m^{*}\left(R\cap A\right)$

and:

$m^{*}\left(R\cap A\right)\leq m^{*}\left(R\cap B\right)+m^{*}\left(A\bigtriangleup B\right)=m^{*}\left(R\cap B\right)$

Proved is now that $m^{*}\left(R\cap A\right)=m^{*}\left(R\cap B\right)$
for any $R\subseteq X$.

Taking $R=X$ we find: $m^{*}\left(A\right)=m^{*}\left(B\right)$.

Observe that $A^{c}\bigtriangleup B^{c}=A\triangle B$ telling us
that likewise we can find that $m^{*}\left(R\cap A^{c}\right)=m^{*}\left(R\cap B^{c}\right)$
for any $R\subseteq X$.

Making use of measurability of $A$ we find for any $R\subseteq X$:

$m^{*}\left(R\cap B\right)+m^{*}\left(R\cap B^{c}\right)=m^{*}\left(R\cap A\right)+m^{*}\left(R\cap A^{c}\right)=m^{*}\left(R\right)$

and conclude that $B$ is measurable.

So we end up with: $$m(A)=m^{*}(A)=m^{*}(B)=m(B)$$

Comment: Is m*(A) = m*(B) => m(A) = m(B)  right?

Comment: Yes, because both sets are measurable. $m$ is actually $m^{*}$ restricted to the collection of the sets that are measurable with respect to $m^{*}$.

Comment: You are welcome.